# can't set google api as target in android

Tags: android, google-api, target, android-virtual-device

I have installed google API but when I try to change the target of the emulator to google API, I don't have the option to change the target. Is there another way to set the target to google API?

Comment: i have tried that but still dont have the option to change the target

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse after the download?

Comment: just restarted it and its working now

Answer (score 1):

it should work with a new avd.
look at [this][1]

if you see no API to choose maybe your google API isn't installed correctly.

ps: sent from phone, maybe the link isn't clickable

[1]url=" eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/configureAVD.html"